# Control inter-paragraph spacing

Tags: ms-word, spacing, paragraph

In using OfficeR to generate MS Word documents, is there a means to control how much space appears on the page between paragraphs? Successive calls to body_add_par() insert space between which is too wide for my purpose. I can't find any reference to controlling this in officer.pdf or in the README.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Inter-paragraph spacing in Word is controlled by the .SpaceBefore and .SpaceAfter settings. For example:

```
With Selection
  With .ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBefore = 6
    .SpaceAfter = 6
  End With
End With
```

Ideally, though, you'd apply these to a Style definition (once), then apply that Style to the paragraphs concerned.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I had the wrong notion. So, the style should be defined in my document template file. There is no function in OfficeR to define it, but once defined in my .docx template, I can apply the style with OfficeR.